# Get string name from a relative path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server (say `testable`). And in that I have only one column (say `testcolumn`). In this column, I have 100 + records. Each record is of the following format.

```
C:\Test1\Test2\Majorrecords\minorrecords\imp\impfiolename1.txt  
/opt/home/test/admincreatedbyme/user1/user1recs/impinfo.sys
```

I actually need to trim or get only the last part of the data. In our example only `impfiolename1.txt` or `impinfo.sys`. Logic is that we have to get to the end of the string an do a reverse and get to the first `/` or `\`.

Comment: You need to only get last name & reverse of forward slash or backward slash

Comment: What SQL are you using? Is it SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below answer is assuming you are using SQL Server.

Here is the code that you need:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(testcolumn, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(REPLACE(testcolumn, '/', '\'))) - 1) AS FileName
FROM testable
```

First, there is a `REPLACE` to change forward slashes to backslashes so further logic can be just for basckslash. Then `REVERSE` function is used to get text in reverse order. Using `CHARINDEX` you get the index of last backslash. And then using `RIGHT` function you take only the number of symbols that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I did not got your question totally but trying to achieve your exepectation.

1. You need Reverse of the `Slashes`

`Declare @Reverse as varchar(1000)
set @Reverse = 'C:\Test1\Test2\Majorrecords\minorrecords\imp\impfiolename1.txt';
declare @rrr varchar(1000)`

2. You need only last Part of the `String`

`select  RIGHT(@Reverse, charindex('/', reverse(@rrr), 1) -1)`

Comment: @Sriharsha Karanth Please comment if I have made any mistakes

Comment: Thank You Sir, Hardik. Unfortunately i will be able to do it tomorrow morning. Please excuse me till the time and i will get back to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also Hardik, if we could generalize the query. I mean you have taken here the first record which ends with "impfiolename1.txt", i have 100 records similar to these. @Reverse is holding only the first record....could you please help? Thank you

Comment: You need to put it in your select clause. like Select  RIGHT(@Reverse, charindex('/', reverse(@rrr), 1) -1) from your tablename

Comment: Hi Hardik, sorry for the delay. It gives a Null value. Thank you for your time.